# How to transpose mysql table rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Here is what my current mysql table looks like:

```
PunchID EmpID   PunchEvent  PunchDateTime
1       0456    clockin     5/14/2013 8:36:26 AM
48      0456    breakout    5/14/2013 12:01:29 PM
53      0456    breakin     5/14/2013 12:28:31 PM
54      0456    clockout    5/14/2013 2:28:33 PM
57      0456    clockin     5/15/2013 7:38:34 AM
58      0456    breakout    5/15/2013 7:38:39 AM
59      0456    breakin     5/15/2013 7:38:41 AM
60      0456    clockout    5/15/2013 7:38:42 AM
```

Now I want to return a result set that is grouped based on the day of the week like so:

```
Day       ClockIn      BreakOut    BreakIn      ClockOut
Tuesday   8:36:26 AM  12:01:29 PM  12:28:31 PM  2:28:33 PM
Wednesday 7:38:34 AM  etc, etc...
```

This is my current query.  But it only returns the first punch for each day.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%W') as day, PunchEvent, DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%l:%m:%s %p') as time FROM timeclock_punchlog WHERE EmpID = '0456' GROUP BY DATE(PunchDateTime) ORDER BY PunchDateTime ASC;
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks
Mike

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167719/how-to-transpose-mysql-rows-and-repeat-column-headers][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962000/join-tables-and-transpose-columns-and-rows][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167719/how-to-transpose-mysql-rows-and-repeat-column-headers
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962000/join-tables-and-transpose-columns-and-rows

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%W') DAY,
        MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'ClockIn' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%r') END) ClockIn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'BreakOut' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%r') END) BreakOut,
        MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'BreakIn' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%r') END) BreakIn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'ClockOut' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%r') END) ClockOut
FROM    tableName
WHERE   EmpID = 456
GROUP   BY DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%W')
ORDER   BY PunchDateTime
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4fab/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║    DAY    ║   CLOCKIN   ║  BREAKOUT   ║   BREAKIN   ║  CLOCKOUT   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Tuesday   ║ 08:36:26 AM ║ 12:01:29 PM ║ 12:28:31 PM ║ 02:28:33 PM ║
║ Wednesday ║ 07:38:34 AM ║ 07:38:39 AM ║ 07:38:41 AM ║ 07:38:42 AM ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: I'm guessing this would not work if there were multiple of each PunchEvent per day?

Comment: what do you mean by `multiple of each PunchEvent per day`?

Comment: If I had 3 'breakin' and 3 'breakout' for Tueday, would it show those?

Comment: if you have those records, how will the output gonna look like?

Comment: Well, I guess the number of columns would be arbitrary depending on how many breaks the user took that day.  This probably isn't possible with MySQL.

Comment: JW, do you know how I could calculate the TIMEDIFF between clockin and breakout as a 6th column?

Comment: btw, I figured out how to do the TIMEDIFF

Comment: @JohnWoo Was `Max(..)` chosen arbitrarily? By choosing `Max(..)`, you are showing the latest data. In this case, obviously, there is not enough data to make a difference. I just want to clear up whether `Max(..)` is the most suitable aggregate function here.