# How to change Columns to Rows in a table in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, tabular

I am not finding how to achieve the following with *iReport* Designer.

Suppose I create the following table:

```
Field1 Field2 .....Fieldn
-------------------------
Val1   Val2   .....Valn
```

how can I display a table like the following:

```
Field1 Val1
Field2 Val2
.
.
.
Fieldn Valn
```

Comment: You can try this solution: [dispay values in detail band as TRANSPOSE](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/524244/dispay-values-detail-band-transpose). Other links: [IReport Convert Rows to columns](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/537821/ireport-convert-rows-columns)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL as your dataset you can transpose the data in your query.
[How to transpose mysql table rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568228/how-to-transpose-mysql-table-rows-into-columns)