# How to display multiple row values into single row

Tags: php, mysql, database, rows, database-table

Here my table is like this

Leave_Type            Leave_Balance

```
CL              12
PL              10
```

Now i want to display my data like below

Leave_Type_CL   Leave_Type_PL   Leave_Balance_CL    Leave_Balance_PL

```
CL      PL      12          10
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: And you HAVE to do this in MySQL?

Comment: there will be 100 of records than it will be 100 of columns?

Comment: [TRY THIS QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568228/how-to-transpose-mysql-table-rows-into-columns) its a hint...This is also known as Transposing..

Comment: leave_type and leave_balance are columns , previously Leave_type values are CL,PL inserted in 2 rows but now i want to display it into 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
   group_concat(CONVERT(Leave_Type, CHAR(2)) separator ' '),
   ' ',
   group_concat(CONVERT(Leave_Balance, CHAR(2)) separator ' ')
) FROM Leave_Table;
```