# how to merge multiple rows with same id mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, buddypress

I'm new posting here but the community have been my best resource on my projects so far.
I'm a dumb/dummy Mysql "wanna be" and I'm in the middle of a project that is making me go mad.

I have a table from wordpress plugin buddypress that pairs meta_key and meta_values in order to create something akin to a taxonomy. My duty is to use these paired values to implement an advanced group search. Here is the original table:

```
--------------------------------------------
id | group_id | meta_key           | meta_value
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | time-zone          | Kwajalein
2  | 1        | playstyle          | hardcore
3  | 1        | recruiting-status  | Open
4  | 1        | ilvl               | 115
5  | 1        | main-raid          | Final Coil of Bahamut
6  | 1        | voicechat          | fc.teamspeak3.com
```

etc....

Using a view I managed to create a more friendly searchable table for begginers :

---

```
gid| time-zone| playstyle  | main-raid
--------------------------------------------
1  |          |            | 
1  |Kwajalein |            | 
1  |          | hardcore   | 
1  |          |            | 
1  |          |            | Final Coil of Bahamut
1  |          |            |
```

And here is the view code:

```
SELECT distinct
group_id AS 'gid',
IF(meta_key='recruiting-status',meta_value,'') AS 'Recruitment',
IF(meta_key='server',meta_value,'') AS 'server',
IF(meta_key='time-zone',meta_value,'') AS 'tzone',
IF(meta_key='main-raid',meta_value,'') AS 'raid',
IF(meta_key='raid-days',meta_value,'') AS 'days',
IF(meta_key='playstyle',meta_value,'') AS 'playstyle',
IF(meta_key='raid-progression',meta_value,'') AS 'progression',
IF(meta_key='raid-time',meta_value,'') AS 'time',
IF(meta_key='tanker-spot',meta_value,'') AS 'tank',
IF(meta_key='healer-spot',meta_value,'') AS 'healer',
IF(meta_key='melee-dps-spot',meta_value,'') AS 'melee',
IF(meta_key='ranged-dps-spot',meta_value,'') AS 'ranged',
IF(meta_key='magic-dps-spot',meta_value,'') AS 'magic',
IF(meta_key='ilvl',meta_value,'') AS 'ilvl',
IF(meta_key='voicechat',meta_value,'') AS 'voice',
IF(meta_key='voicechatpass',meta_value,'') AS 'voicep',
FROM wpstatic_bp_groups_groupmeta
```

The point is, I need to merge that result (view) so all the group_id=1 or 2 or 3, etc stand in one single row, like this:

---

```
gid| time-zone| playstyle  | main-raid
--------------------------------------------
1  |Kwajalein | hardcore   | Final Coil of Bahamut
2  |SaoPaulo  | regular    | Second Coil of Bahamut
```

etc

Can anyone help me there?

Comment: This is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568228/how-to-transpose-mysql-table-rows-into-columns but I think you can add to the end of your view `GROUP  BY gid` maybe?

Comment: I tried and got a row with no data besides the gid column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just surround your `IF`s in a `MAX`, or another aggregate function that will capture the non-empty strings (e.g., `GROUP_CONCAT`), and add a `GROUP BY group_id` add the end. For example,

```
SELECT
group_id AS gid,
MAX(IF(meta_key='recruiting-status',meta_value,'')) AS 'Recruitment',
MAX(IF(meta_key='server',meta_value,'')) AS 'server',
...
FROM wpstatic_bp_groups_groupmeta
GROUP BY group_id
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it right away, I have tried the group by id but not the max. :)