# Need to Convert Columns into Rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I had the following sample data

```
------------------------------|------|-
Sishya School                 |  3   | 
------------------------------|------|--
Chettinad Vidhyashram         |  2   |
------------------------------|------|--
Asan Memorial School          |  8   |
------------------------------|------|--
Maharishi Vidhya  Mandir      |  1   | 
------------------------------|------|--
PSBB Memorial School          |  4   |
------------------------------|------|--
D.V.S Public School           |  2   |
------------------------------|------|--
St.Mary’s School              |  5   | 
------------------------------|------|--
```

I want to convert columns into Rows so that the table should look like the following,

```
---------|----------------|-----------|-----------|---------|---------|-------
Sishya   |     Chettinad  |   Asan    |  Maharishi| PSBB    |   D.V.S |St.Mary’s
School   |    Vidhyashram |   Memorial|  Vidhya   | Memorial|   Public| School 
         |                |    School |  Mandir   |  School |   School|
---------|----------------|-----------|-----------|---------|---------|-------
         |                |           |           |         |         | 
3        |        2       |      8    |       1   |       4 |      2  |     5
---------|----------------|-----------|-----------|---------|---------|---------
```

Please help me to get my problem solve.

Comment: What you have tried yet ?

Comment: can you provide table details ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose   or    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568228/how-to-transpose-mysql-table-rows-into-columns

Comment: Thats called paivot table. [This SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) can help you.

Comment: @poornima , this school list is static or dynamic?

Comment: Without pivot table i need to carry out this one

Comment: @Poornima this is called pivoting, so you cannot fo this without pivot tables. The duplicate link I provided describes both static and dynamic pivoting in mysql. Pls slso consider doing this transformation in your application. I may be more efficient.

Comment: I am getting all datas dynamically from database .For pivot table it seems to use static data.Is pivot table is possible to handle dynamic data?If possible,please send some link for pivot table with dynamic data

Comment: whats wrong with keeping the same sql query then having your "application" provide you with the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be below solution help you to solve your problem , you need to do some changes as per your table structure.

For this solution you have to make a stored procedure.

If this is your table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `school` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Below solution is working if above is your table structure.

```
   SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = (2056 * 2056);

SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
             CONCAT(
               'MAX(CASE WHEN school.name ="',m.name,'"'
                                ' THEN school.value END)"',m.name , '"'))
                                INTO @sql  
                                            from school as m;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT value,',@sql,
                  ' FROM school');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Do changes as per your table structure.

This solution is also helpful for multiple table ,I hope this may help you to solve your problem.

Comment: yes this solves i think if my need in SQL.But I need to handle the same situation in MYSQL.

Comment: @Poornima , this solution is for mysql not for sql , in sql there is a pivot function is available but not in mysql,  so you have to follow this structure. If you provide me dump of your table structure and data then i will make perfect query for you.

Comment: @Poornima , check above solution.

Comment: ok thanks chirag.. will try this and send u result

Comment: don't forgot to appreciate my work.

Comment: Thank you very much chirag patel..Your post is really helpful.Good job...Hats off to your work..

Comment: This is exactly the solution described in the duplicate topic along with explanation that is missing here.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for your great help too...