# MySQL Query to use to change table orientation (vertical to horizontal)

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

So I have this table:

```
Year | MonthInterval | RainfallIndex
2016 | Jan-Feb       | 1.03
2016 | Feb-Mar       | 0.23
2016 | Mar-Apr       | 2.30
```

What query can I apply to transform the table into this:

```
Year | Jan-Feb | Feb-Mar | Mar-Apr 
2016 | 1.03    | 0.23    | 2.30
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568228/how-to-transpose-mysql-table-rows-into-columns

Comment: Google:  "mysql pivot query".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement:

```
   CREATE TABLE rainfall_pivot AS
  SELECT
    Year,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(MonthInterval) = 'Jan-Feb'
      THEN RainfallIndex
        ELSE 0 END) AS "Jan-Feb",
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(MonthInterval) = 'Feb-Mar'
      THEN RainfallIndex
        ELSE 0 END) AS "Feb-Mar",
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(MonthInterval) = 'Mar-Apr'
      THEN RainfallIndex
        ELSE 0 END) AS "Mar-Apr"
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1;
```